# 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead

Tags: javascript, webkit

Здравствуйте. Возникают 2 непонятных предупреждения

> 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
>
> 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.

Не могу понять их причину. Возникают в Хроме и Опере. Хром версии 43.0.2357.65 (32 бит).
[image: скриншот консоли Хрома]

```
/* some code here ... */
function TestFunc() {
    return 100;
}
var tstFunc = xnLib.once(TestFunc);

var result = tstFunc();
console.log("#5");
console.assert(result === 100, "Expression result === 100 failed. result = " + result);
console.log("#6");
result = tstFunc();
console.assert(typeof result === 'undefined', "Expression result === 'undefined' failed. result = " + result);

console.info("'Named function' test ..... OK");
```

Код ф-ции **once** (позволяет запускаться ф-циям только 1 раз):

```
var xnLib = (function () {

return {
    once: xnOnce
};


function xnOnce(fn, shouldPerInstance) {
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        console.error("'fn' is not a function: ", (typeof fn));
        debugger;
        return void 0;
    }
    shouldPerInstance = typeof shouldPerInstance === 'undefined' || shouldPerInstance === true;
    var done = false;

    return function () {
        if (!!fn.name) {
            console.log("#1");
            if (!this.__once__) {
                this.__once__ = {};
                console.log("#1.1");
                Object.defineProperty(this, "__once__", {
                    enumerable: false
                });
            }
            console.log("#2");
            if (this.__once__[fn.name]) {
                return void 0;
            }
            console.log("#3");
            this.__once__[fn.name] = true;
            console.log("#4");
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        if (shouldPerInstance === true) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty("__once__") && this.__once__) {
                return void 0;
            }
            this.__once__ = true;
            Object.defineProperty(this, "__once__", {
                enumerable: false,
                writable: false,
                configurable: false
            });
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return done ? void 0 : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments))
    };
}

})();
```

Как видно из кода предупреждения возникают на выражении `Object.defineProperty(this, "__once__", { enumerable: false });`. Если я комментирую это выражение, то предупреждения начинают выдаваться после метки #4, т.е. на выражении `return fn.apply(this, arguments);`. Я в веб-программировании новичок, поэтому сложно понять сути этих предупреждений. Буду признателен за помощь (и любую критику по коду)